# Why we need childEls in extjs - where to use this?

Tags: extjs

Could you please explain for what I have to use this? I am having one example of this, but I think why should we just set the .css ID or CLASS for that in h1 tag? Why do we need this **childEls**? And when I use the same techniques for the **msg** it is not working why?

1) Why should we use this config?
2) Where to use?
3) Can't we define .css class or id and out the styling?
4) When I use this same technique for **msg**, it is not working.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
// Explicitly create a Container
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    renderTpl: [
        '<h1 id="{id}-title" data-ref="title">{title}</h1>',
        '<p>{msg}</p>',
    ],
    renderData: {
        title: "Error",
        msg: "Something went wrong"
    },
    childEls: ["title"],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp){
            console.log(cmp);
            // After rendering the component will have a title property
            cmp.title.setStyle({color: "red"});
        }
    }
});
```

});

For the mes I used this code.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
// Explicitly create a Container
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    renderTpl: [
        '<h1 id="{id}-title" data-ref="title">{title}</h1>',
        '<p id="{id}-msg" data-ref="msg">{msg}</p>',
    ],
    renderData: {
        title: "Error",
        msg: "Something went wrong"
    },
    childEls: ["title","msg"],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp){
            console.log(cmp);
            // After rendering the component will have a title property
            cmp.title.setStyle({color: "red"});
            cmp.msg.setStyle({color: "green"});
        }
    }
});
```

});

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `childEls` config, the constructor of your component will create a reference to your childEls items inside the component.

So lets say your main component has an id of `component-2020`, your template will create

```
<h1 id="component-2020-title" data-ref="title">content of your renderData.title</h1>
<p id="component-2020-msg" data-ref="msg">content of your renderData.title</p>
```

And now because of your childEls config, every time you call
component.title or component.msg
you will get a reference to these specific elements and will be able to use all the `Ext.dom.Elements` methods (described here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) on them.

So it is much more useful than just replacing CSS

You could change your afterrender method to something like this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(cmp){
        console.log(cmp);
        // After rendering the component will have a title property
        cmp.title.setStyle({color: "red"});
        cmp.title.fadeOut({duration: 2000}).fadeIn({duration: 2000});
        cmp.msg.setStyle({color: "green"});
    }
}
```

- Your msg block should work just fine. I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: OMG now it is working. Nothing changed. As you said it should work and its working now. Don't know what happened. Anyway thx for your explanation.